# Virtual CAN Bus Simulator

Tags: can-bus, socketcan

I apologize ahead of time if this seems to similar to another question or if it seems like it has already been answered. I felt it was uniquely detailed enough to warrant its own question.

I am trying to find a virtual CAN bus simulator (or some way to easily make one) that will simply generate CAN bus messages. I want to be able to just send the raw CAN messages  bit by bit to another device (using GPIO) for independent analysis by another program.

Additionally if anyone knows of something that would generate authentic vehicle CAN bus messages (or even just a database of real CAN messages) that would help.

Currently I am looking at SocketCAN but I am not sure it would work. I appreciate any thoughts or advice.

Answer (score 4):

You could look into the free software BUSMASTER by ETAS. 
http://www.etas.com/en/products/applications_busmaster.php

It will let you send raw CAN data. If you have a database, it well let you send "real world" data, too. If you want to send real vehicle data, you could log the CAN bus of a vehicle and use BUSMATER to replay it.

It supports many CAN hardware devices, included those by Kvaser. 
https://www.kvaser.com/products/kvaser-leaf-light-hs-v2/

Answer (score 2):

Check out "open garages" YouTube channel for help. This  https://github.com/zombieCraig/ICSim?files=1      is a great instrument cluster simulator. The README file will explain how to download it and launch the sim. It will generate CAN traffic as you increase mph, lock/unlock doors, etc in the simulator. You can use the virtual can device with it via socketCAN. This way will require a Linux OS and wine (used to launch exe files on Linux, exe's are windows files) because the simulator files are executables for reasons idk haha. I'm starting out and found it very helpful.